# How can I configure QGIS to add a authentication key to all the WMS requests it makes?

Tags: qgis, wms, authentication

I'm trying to use a WMS service that requires a subscription key be appended to all requests that are made to it.

I can sort of make it work by using `http://machine.com/mappingserver?subscription-key=my-secret-key?` as the base URL when adding the WMS. But this fails by default unless I remember to tick the `Ignore GetMap/GetTile URL in capabilities` boxes - then I get a map and can do identify but I can't see the legend that was carefully designed to help me understand the map.

Now, I can add an authentication configuration to my WMS service when I add it to QGIS, but none of the options seem to help me just specify a key and token that need to be added to any request. I thought I could fool the ESRI token store into doing this but it doesn't seem to want to help me out.

So, I guess my question boils down to am I missing something obvious or should I start reading the authentication code over the weekend?

Comment: as I am sure you know, if you're using the authkey module with GeoServer, the GetCapabilities call will automatically append the supplied authkey to the URLs that it returns, so QGIS just works beautifully with GeoServer and authkey.  So you must be wanting a solution for a different mapping server?

Your `Ignore GetMap/GetTile URL in capabilities` solution works best for me in this case.

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html

Comment: wchich version of QGIS do you use? in my version the ignore option includes the get legend uri ("Ignore GetMap/GetTile/GetLegendGraphic URI reported in capabilities")

Comment: It does indeed because I wrote a patch for that some time ago - I don't want to be telling users to have to remember to tick those boxes though

Answer (score 0):

The token needs to be provided on every `xlink:href` attribute in the `Capabilities` document like `LegendURL`. If the parameter is provided correctly QGIS will have no issue displaying the legend. So I don't think this is something QGIS needs to deal with rather the server needs to provide the correct `URLs` already with the token appended.

Comment: probably, but I'm trying to talk to servers in the wild that I have no control over

Comment: If the server is out of your hand I guess having something similar to the `HTTP Headers` options like a key / value list for extra parameters which are always appended to every sub-request of a WMS source would be good to have.