# Authenticating WFS from GeoServer with Keycloak in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, authentication

I have a Geosever with the Keycloak Community extension (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/keycloak/index.html) installed.

Authentication with the Keycloak Server in the Browser works fine.

Now I need to authenticate my WFS against Keycloak out of QGIS.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: related question - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371362/how-can-i-configure-qgis-to-add-a-authentication-key-to-all-the-wms-requests-it

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working with these settings:

[image: QGis authentication with Keycloak]

Under `Settings` --> `Authentication` create a new authentication configuration of type `OAuth2 authentication`, then enter:

- `Token URL`: enter keycloak's token endpoint. You can get this URL by clicking on the `OpenID Endpoint Configuration` link in your keycloak's realm settings and searching for `token_endpoint`.
- `Client ID`: name of your client.
- `Client secret`: you can get it on the client configuration's `Credentials` tab.
- `Username` and `Password`
- `Scope`: `openid`

There is also an *alternative* method - **enable basic authentication**. For me, all I had to do was to set `Browser Flow` to `http challenge` in the client configuration's `Settings` tab:

[image]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808046/does-keycloak-support-basic-authentication) thread, your must also configure `Access Type: confidential` and `Direct Access Grants: Enabled` on your client for this to work.

With this configuration even GeoServer is now asking for creadentials using basic authentication instead of redirecting to KeyCloak's login page, which I find more user-friendly.